# Помогите отследить словарь в Пайтоне

Tags: python, json, словари

я учу пайтон и для опыта делаю свой небольшой проект. Суть проекта заключается запарсить json файл по ссылке и получить словарь, данный словарь каждый раз обновляется. И я хочу сохранять его в списке по типу [Словарь 1] -> [Словарь 2, Словарь 1] -> [Словарь 3, Словарь 2, Словарь 1] и так далее

```
from main import get_last_data
import time

data_list = []
while True:
    get_last_data()
    data_list.append((get_last_data()))


print(list((data_list)))
time.sleep(1)
```

У меня выводит:

```
   [{'92207140241': 2}]
   [{'92207140241': 2}, {'92207140241': 2}]
   [{'92207140241': 2}, {'92207140241': 2}, {'92207140241': 2}]
```

А должен:

```
   [{'92207140241': 2}]
   [{'92207140242': 4}, {'92207140241': 2}]
   [{'92207140243': 1}, {'92207140242': 4}, {'92207140241': 2}]
```

Чуток переписал код:

```
   from main import get_last_data
   import time

   data_list = ['start']

   while True:
   get_last_data()
   if get_last_data() != data_list[0]:
       data_list.insert(0, get_last_data())

   else:
      continue

   print(data_list)
   time.sleep(5)
```

Главная проблема в том что в цикле когда вызывает функцию переменная не меняется, и из за этого выводит один и те же данные

Comment: А что делает `get_last_data`?

Comment: @oleksandrigo 'get_last_data'  парсит json, и получает из него последний словарь. Но сам json файл постоянно меняется код должен сохранить последний словарь, потом со временем проверить 'get_last_data' если ключ поменялся добавить этот словарь к предыдущей

Comment: Можете добавлять не в конец через `list.append(data)`, а использовать `list.insert(0, data)`

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T да чуток переписал код,но главная проблема в том что он данные не обновляет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался наконец:

```
data_list = []
last_number = int(*get_last_data().keys()) 

while True:
    if last_number == int(*get_last_data().keys()):
        data_list.insert(0, get_last_data())
        last_number = int(*get_last_data().keys()) + 1
    else:
        continue

    print(data_list)
```

Результат:

```
[{'92207150093': 4}]
[{'92207150094': 2}, {'92207150093': 4}]
```

Comment: С одной стороны если вы случайно пропустите одно обновление у вас скрипт перестанет работать. С другой стороны добавьте всё-таки какой-нибудь `sleep` в цикл, иначе ваш скрипт будет жрать процессор как не в себя.

Comment: @CrazyElf да добавил условие чтобы код работал  один раз в минуту, код получилось слишком медленным (9 сек для для результата) но в принципе для моих нужд не так критично

Answer (score 0):

Вы добавляете в конец списка, а вам нужно в начало.

```
from main import get_last_data
import time

data_list = []
while True:
   # get_last_data() # зачем вы вызываете эту функцию без сохранения результата ее работы в переменную ?
    new_data = get_last_data()
    if new_data not in data_list:
        data_list = [new_data] + data_list # 1 вариант
        data_list.insert(0, new_data) # 2 вариант

print(data_list) # list() не нужен, потому что data_list и без того список
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Просто не корректно написал. Главное  там что данные вызванные в цикле он не обновляется и показывает одно  и то же, а я хотел бы добавить словарь и после вызвал функцию, если ключ изменился добавить его в список и так далее

Comment: @onpaper изменил код